# How to prevent IntelliJ IDEA from closing multiline comments?

Tags: intellij-idea

In the Java/Groovy IDEA editor, if I type `/*` above some existing code, then arrow down to some place and press enter, IDEA automatically adds `*/` (in the wrong spot, I might add).  This is driving me crazy.  How can I disable this behavior?

**EDIT**: Screenshots added as requested.

Comment started, before enter pressed (all is OK with this):
[image]

After enter is pressed at the end of the "hello world 1" print statement line where IDEA has automatically inserted the `*/`:
[image]

Comment: Pls. could you describe it with screenshots. I am not sure if I got you right.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your Screenshots, I am afraid, it is not possible by default.

If you typed `/*`  the next press with Enter below that line will always add the closing comment line `*/`.

That's the expected behaviour for the most cases.

You can prevent this by first typing `*/` somewhere below the lines you want to press Enter.

Although, you can request your desired behaviour from Jetbrains via https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.